# Edit the Logged In Profile with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter and need some help :). 
I managed to build a CRUD functions with ajax over some tutorials and I can Edit, Add new, Delete all user shown on my page. What I want now is when i Login with a user I just want the Logged in Profile to be Edited, not others. Please if someone can help me how can I manage to do that.  Thank You in Advance.

Employee.php Controller

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct sripct access allowed');

Class Employee extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Employee_m', 'm');
    }


function index()
{
    $this->load->view('employee/index');

}

public function showAllEmployee()
{
    $result = $this->m->showAllEmployee();
    echo json_encode($result);
}

public function add_user()
{
    $result = $this->m->add_user();
    $msg['success'] = false;
    $msg['type'] = 'add';
    if ($result) {
        $msg['success'] = true;
    }
    echo json_encode($msg);
}

public function edit_user()
{
    $result = $this->m->edit_user();
    echo json_encode($result);
}

public function update_user()
{
    $result = $this->m->update_user();
    $msg['success'] = false;
    $msg['type'] = 'update';
    if ($result) {
        $msg['success'] = true;
    }
    echo json_encode($msg);
}

public function delete_user()
{
    $result = $this->m->delete_user();
    $msg['success'] = false;
    if ($result) {
        $msg['success'] = true;
    }
    echo json_encode($msg);
}
```

Employee_m Model

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct sripct access allowed');
class Employee_m extends CI_Model
{

public function showAllEmployee()
{

    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


public function add_user()
{
    $field = array(
        'firstname' => $this->input->post('txtFirstName'),
        'lastname' => $this->input->post('txtLastName'),
        'username' => $this->input->post('txtUsername'),
        'user_email' => $this->input->post('txtUserEmail'),
        'user_password' => $this->input->post('txtUserPassword')
    );
    $this->db->insert('users',$field);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

public function get_id(){
    $id = $this->input->get('id');
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


public function update_user()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('txtId');
    $field = array(
        'firstname' => $this->input->post('txtFirstName'),
        'lastname' => $this->input->post('txtLastName'),
        'username' => $this->input->post('txtUsername'),
        'user_email' => $this->input->post('txtUserEmail'),
        'user_password' => $this->input->post('txtUserPassword')
    );
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $this->db->update('users',$field);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function delete_user()
{
    $id = $this->input->get('id');
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $this->db->delete('users');
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

Index View

```
<?php $this->load->view('components/page_head'); ?>

<?php
if (isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])) {
    $username = ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['username']);
    $id = ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id']);

} else {
    header("location: user_authentication");
}
?>

<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="alert alert-success" style="display: none;">

    </div>
<button id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-success">Add New</button>
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>e-Mail</td>
        <td>Actions</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="showdata">

    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="myForm" action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                    <input type="hidden" name="txtId" value="0">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="label-control col-md-4">First Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="label-control col-md-4">Last Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="txtLastName" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="label-control col-md-4">Username</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="txtUsername" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="label-control col-md-4">e-Mail</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="email" name="txtUserEmail" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="label-control col-md-4">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="password" name="txtUserPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="******">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div id="deleteModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Delete</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Do you want to delete this record?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<script>
    $(function () {
        showAllEmployee();

        // Add New
        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#myModal').find('.modal-title').text('Add new user');
            $('#myForm').attr('action','<?php echo base_url() ?>employee/add_user');
        });

        $('#btnSave').click(function () {
//            alert('test');
            var url = $('#myForm').attr('action');
            var data = $('#myForm').serialize();

            // validate the form
            var firstname = $('input[name=txtFirstName]');
            var lastname = $('input[name=txtLastName]');
            var username = $('input[name=txtUsername]');
            var user_email = $('input[name=txtUserEmail]');
            var user_password = $('input[name=txtUserPassword]');
            var result = '';
            if (firstname.val()==''){
                firstname.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
            }else {
                firstname.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
                result +='1';
            }
            if (lastname.val()==''){
                lastname.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
            }else {
                lastname.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
                result +='2';
            }
            if (username.val()==''){
                username.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
            }else {
                username.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
                result +='3';
            }
            if (user_email.val()==''){
                user_email.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
            }else {
                user_email.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
                result +='4';
            }
            if (user_password.val()==''){
                user_password.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
            }else {
                user_password.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
                result +='5';
            }


            if(result == '12345'){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'ajax',
                    method: 'post',
                    url: url,
                    data: data,
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.success){
                            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                            $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                            if(response.type=='add'){
                                var type = 'added'
                            }else if(response.type=='update'){
                                var type ="updated"
                            }
                            $('.alert-success').html('User '+type+' successfully').fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
                            showAllEmployee();
                        }else{
                            alert('Error');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Could not add Data ');
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        //edit
        $('#showdata').on('click', '.item-edit', function() {

            var id = $(this).attr('data');
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#myModal').find('.modal-title').text('edit user');
            $('#myForm').attr('action','<?php echo base_url() ?>employee/update_user');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'ajax',
                method: 'get',
                url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>employee/edit_user',
                data: {id: id},
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('input[name=txtFirstName]').val(data.firstname);
                    $('input[name=txtLastName]').val(data.lastname);
                    $('input[name=txtUsername]').val(data.username);
                    $('input[name=txtUserEmail]').val(data.user_email);
                    $('input[name=txtUserPassword]').val(data.user_password);
                    $('input[name=txtId]').val(data.id);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Could not Edit Data');
                }
            });
        });

        //delete
        $('#showdata').on('click', '.item-delete', function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('data');
            $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
            $('#btnDelete').unbind().click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'ajax',
                    method: 'get',
                    async: false,
                    url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>employee/delete_user',
                    data: {id: id},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        if(response.success){
                            $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');
                            $('.alert-success').html('User deleted successfully').fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
                            showAllEmployee();
                        }else{
                            alert('Error');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Error deleting');
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        //function
        function showAllEmployee() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>employee/showAllEmployee',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        html += '<tr>' +
                            '<td>'+data[i].id+'</td>'+
                            '<td>' + data[i].firstname + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].lastname + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].username + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].user_email + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' +
                            '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info item-edit" data="'+data[i].id+'">Edit</a>' +
                            '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger item-delete" data="'+data[i].id+'">Delete</a>' +
                            '</td>' +
                            '</tr>';
                    }
                    $('#showdata').html(html);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Could not get Data from Database');
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <?php
    echo "Hello <b id='welcome'><i>" . $username . "</i> !</b>";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Your ID is " . $id;
    echo "<br/>";
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>user_authentication/logout">Logout</a>
</div>
<?php $this->load->view('components/page_tail'); ?>
```

Comment: Just observation, but at the top of your model and controller you have spelled "script" wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch that user details to index page to avoid edting for other or need to set some condition  such as passing users id on edit check if it same as edit id and then proceed for edit opertaion or else return some message

Comment: Thnx for the help :)